# How to check large data fast in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of 20000 - 50000 words. I have few pages of text, let's say 1000 words. I want to check if each of this 1000 words is in my big list and count the matches, but checking word after word is way too cumbersome and unnecessary. I imagine real life dictionary, where you can find the word you seek in few checks, would be the fastest. Am I right, and how to achieve that/what would be the best way?

I think of using sqlite and some queries.

Comment: A code would always run as the processor would execute it. There is not such thing as boosting it up! You should either *upgrade your machine*; such as add more cores to machine or add more memory to support the processing, or remove this thought.

Comment: this does simply not work without checking word for word... the `fastest` way would be a `List<string word, int count>` and using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I imagine real life dictionary, where you can find the word you seek in few checks, would be the fastest.

That's actually a really good example.  Imagine that you know nothing of the language in the dictionary, except for its alphabet.  You can still find the word very quickly.  How?

- Check somewhere in the middle.  Is the word before or after the word you picked?  Eliminate the entire half of the dictionary which doesn't match.
- Check somewhere in the middle of the remaining values...
- Repeat...

This is called a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).  And it is, indeed, *very* fast.  It simply requires one precondition... The list must be sorted.

If your list is sorted, you can use this as an opportunity to familiarize yourself with one of the fundamental algorithms of computer science, a binary search.  There are *tons* of examples in just about every programming language, and there may even be built-in tools and data types for you.  (For example, I imagine [`SortedList` is going to internally implement a binary search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx) when you reference values within it.

Comment: good catch! This is very good suggestion for writing the binary search suggestion.

Comment: Only limitation of this: it only works if you are searching for a word "starting with". "contains" can't be done in this way.

Comment: @xanatos: Good catch.  The question isn't clear on what a "match" is.  I guess I was assuming a direct binary data comparison.

Comment: If you're looking for an exact match, then a Dictionary with your 20K+ words in it is the way to go. Checking the presence of an item is an O(1) operation. This is because each word in your dictionary will be stored in a specific location in an underlying array based on the result of a hashing function. So checking if a given word exists is as simple as hashing it and seeing if anything is already stored at that location.

Comment: Yes, I need exact matches. This sounds very interesting @Chris, can you explain more/share link that explain?

Comment: Start here to learn about different data structures and how they can be used to solve different problems: http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/computer-science-data-structures/ Then move onto here to learn about using the C# Dictionary http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Note, different Hashset/Dictionary implementations will have different approaches to handling hash collisions (i.e. 2 different keys hashing to the same value), but worry about that later once you understand the basics.